# What's the difference between ^~ and ~ in nginx config

Tags: nginx, regex

I'm configuring nginx and came across "^~", which seems to have a similar functionality as "~". I read the documentation [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) but it's still not clear to me. So how are the following locations different?

```
location ~ /images/* {
        try_files  $uri $uri/ @images;
    }
location ^~ /images/* {
        try_files  $uri $uri/ @images;
    }
```

Comment: This guide gives a better explanation https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms the important part is `It is important to understand that, by default, Nginx will serve regular expression matches in preference to prefix matches. However, it evaluates prefix locations first, allowing for the administer to override this tendency by specifying locations using the = and ^~ modifiers.`

Answer (score 4):

`~` and `^~` are not at all similar. The first indicates a case sensitive regex match (`~*` would be the same in case insensitive), but the second  variant `^~` means that if this location block matches, `nginx` must stop searching for a better (regex) match. It is not a regex match at all in itself.

Example: If you have  location blocks like the following,

```
location /images/ {
     # variant 1 
   }

location ~* .(png|gif|ico|jpg|jpeg)$  { 
     # variant 2
   }
```

and have an URI like `images/test1.png`, `nginx` would first consider variant 1 as a possible match but continue to search further location blocks and end up using variant 2 as the longest matching block and only use variant 1 if it doesn't find anything better. In this example, `images/test2.tif` would have been matched by variant 1 only.

However, is you have

```
location ^~ /images/ {
     # variant 1 
   }
```

as your variant 1, nginx will see that this matches and use it immediately, without searching for better regex matches further down.

[This](https://www.keycdn.com/support/nginx-location-directive/) article explains it a bit better then the [official documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location).